# GRUB Command Line appears after reboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grubrescue, grub-efi

On my computer I have 2 SSDs, one with Windows 10 (up-to-date), the other with Ubuntu (20.04.1) setup in dual boot. I have to switch between OS a couple of times a day, and every time I want to go from Ubuntu to Windows (and want to reboot Ubuntu), the following symptoms appear :

- POST is not shown
- GRUB command-line is shown, and I type `exit` to go back to OS selection
- I select Windows and press Enter
- Black screen (stays indefinitely)
- Hard reset
- POST is shown
- GRUB menu appears and I can now boot into Windows

This appears sometimes when I shut down Windows to go to Ubuntu, but it's fairly rare, while the other way is systematic. But if I select Ubuntu after exiting GRUB command line, the black screen stays a couple of seconds then Ubuntu login screen appears.

This is a relatively new computer (March 2020) and has always been setup this way (except I started with Ubuntu 18.04 and did an upgrade), and this problem has always appeared. This was only a minor annoyance at first since I worked mostly on Ubuntu and didn't have to switch OS that much.

Some details :

- BIOS Secure boot is disabled
- Windows fast boot is disabled
- I tried several `grub-install` and `update-grub` commands found here and on forums but nothing changed
- I installed Boot-Repair and did several repairs, nothing changed
- I did the log dump of Boot-Repair : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y3kHfsCxkx/

Relevant computer hardware (if it can help) :

- Motherboard : ASUS PRIME Z390-P (so UEFI BIOS)
- SSDs : 2 * Kingston M.2 NVMe

Any idea on why this is happening ? And what can I do to fix it ? I'm relatively new to the Linux world, and have not found any way to fix this. Please ask if you need more details, I'll edit this post. Thank you

---

Output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model: SAMSUNG HD502HI 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 7D34D31D-720C-41D9-811E-9DC6EBD665A5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 976773101 sectors (465.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

Output of `sudo nvme list` :

```
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev  
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     50026B728251D61D     KINGSTON SKC2000M8250G                   1         220,93  GB / 250,06  GB    512   B +  0 B   S2780101
/dev/nvme1n1     50026B728251D6AA     KINGSTON SKC2000M8250G                   1         211,00  GB / 250,06  GB    512   B +  0 B   S2780101
```

Comment: Your sda is not shown or shown correctly. What does this show. `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. It says unknown label, There are several labels, but that refers to whether gpt or MBR(msdos) partitioned. Are drives in AHCI mode? Is UEFI updated to latest available. Have you updated SSD firmware to latest available? `sudo nvme list
` You probably have to install nvme-cli.

Comment: sda is a fully encrypted disk (with Veracrypt), I've added gdisk output to my post.

Comment: Don't know about AHCI mode (how can I check ?). UEFI should be up-to-data I'll check next time i'm on Windows (with Asus software). As for SSD firmwire I'll check with Kington software on Windows too. I'll add `nvme list` output to my post

Comment: I do not use virtual installs, but those that have to switch a lot prefer a virtual install as then you have access to both systems. You do give up a bit of performance with virtual install. That drive is fully encrypted must be why its not showing, but usually you still have partitions.

Comment: Ubuntu is mostly for work (Docker for web dev) and Windows mostly for games, but I have some work stuff there too (mostly MS Office). So virtualization is not really a solution...

Comment: if you boot directly from UEFI boot menu, does each system directly boot without issue? Windows often turns fast start up back on with updates and then grub will not boot it. Check that fast start up is still off. Best not to do hard reset. If in Ubuntu use REISUB. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609442/whats-the-difference-between-reisub-and-a-regular-reboot, but that will not work from grub.